# Cannot connect to MySQL server via command line while Workbench can work

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL server running on Windows 7 (technically on a virtual machine but I don't think that matters). I have configured everything and it seemed fine at first. I tried to connect to the server via command line and it worked. Then I tried to connect to it via Workbench and succeeded again. However, I can no longer connect to the server with command prompt ever since that. The client machine is in a different sub-network.

My command is like:

`mysql -host HOST_IP -P PORT -uUSER -pPASSWORD`

And it returns:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'ost' (0)
```

The problem is that while I can connect to the server via Workbench, the command line just won't work. It all happens after I connected with Workbench. Does it has anything to do with Workbench? Or is caused by other issues?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to connect to the host `ost`?

Comment: Try this command, mysql -h HOST_IP -p PORT  -u USER -p PASSWORD

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know, but the IP address is definitely correct.  I have no access to the server on which the virtual machine runs so I'm not sure what exactly is 'ost'.

Comment: @Santosh I think my usage is correct, I have already tried it out. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is no option called "-host". Its either "--host" or "-h".

Comment: Here is URL which has listed all the options, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html

Comment: @Santosh It makes sense. I left out a hyphen. That explains the host name 'ost'. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: After changing the option, did it work?

Comment: @Santosh Yes, it does. Thanks again. The question could be closed now.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Accept the answer by flagging and close question as it will help in future if anyone is searching for same issue.